# PHP7.1.X and PHP7.0.X X64 compile fails

Tags: windows, compiler-errors, 64-bit, php-7

Having issues with X64 compiling on Windows.
Using VC14 and X64 as targets.
On the same machine and with same setup X86 versions compile fine.
Using instructions to compile X64 from following link:

https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild_sdk_2

```
D:\php-sdk2\php-sdk-binary-tools\phpdev\vc14\x64\php-7.1.8-src
$ nmake

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.00.23506.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Recreating build dirs
        bison.exe --output=Zend/zend_ini_parser.c -v -d -p ini_ Zend/zend_ini_pa
rser.y
        bison.exe --output=Zend/zend_language_parser.c -v -d -p zend Zend/zend_l
anguage_parser.y
        type ext\pcre\php_pcre.def > D:\php-sdk2\php-sdk-binary-tools\phpdev\vc1
4\x64\php-7.1.8-src\x64\Release_TS\php7ts.dll.def
        "" -h win32\ -r D:\php-sdk2\php-sdk-binary-tools\phpdev\vc14\x64\php-7.1
.8-src\x64\Release_TS\ -x D:\php-sdk2\php-sdk-binary-tools\phpdev\vc14\x64\php-7
.1.8-src\x64\Release_TS\ win32\build\wsyslog.mc
'-h' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"' : return code '0x1'
Stop.
```

Here is my configure options:

```
D:\php-sdk2\php-sdk-binary-tools\phpdev\vc14\x64\php-7.1.8-src
$ configure --disable-all --enable-cli --enable-cgi --enable-apache2-4handler
PHP Version: 7.1.8
```

Had checked Makefile after being generated by configure command. Had found that there is line:

```
$(MCFILE): win32\build\wsyslog.mc
    $(MC) -h win32\ -r $(BUILD_DIR)\ -x $(BUILD_DIR)\ win32\build\wsyslog.mc
```

and in the Makefile MC is configured by this line:

```
MC="$(MC)"
```

It looks like MC is initialized to null ("") and that is way Makefile fails. What is MC and for what is it used?